# adding logic to redux reducer to persist state

Tags: react-redux

I am working with a react/redux learning project, where I'm building components to host headless CMS content. One part of the application is a dropdown that will select the content from all available content channels in the source CMS.

This works on the first pass, but when I navigate to another page (ie, the detail of a single CMS content item - the first page displays multiple items in a grid) it resets the state back to an initial (empty) variable.

The component is below:

```
import { FETCH_CHANNELS } from '../actions/types';

// set the initial state first
const initialState = {
  isLoading: true,
  data: [],
  error: ""
}

// set the state depending on the dispatch coming in
const channelsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_CHANNELS:
      // reduce the returned state down to an array of options
      // filter here to limit to searchable only
      const activeChannels = [];
      action.payload['channels'].forEach( el => {
        if(el.isChannelSearchable) {
          let singleItem = {
            key: el.channelId,
            value: el.channelId,
            text: el.channelName,
            type: el.channelType
          }
          activeChannels.push(singleItem);
        }
      });
      return {...state, data: activeChannels, isLoading: false};
    case "ERROR":
      return {...state, error: action.msg};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default channelsReducer;
```

My issue here (as I see it), is the initialisation of the initialState constant at the beginning, everytime that the component is refreshed, it is set to empty again. Makes sense.

How can I persist the state that is returned in the FETCH_CHANNELS case (that action is a call to a back end api that returns all channels) so that upon the component remounting it still retains it's state?

Not sure if I have to either (quite possibly none of these are correct):

1. Attempt with some logic in the front end component that is calling this action, to not call it if data already exists?
2. Create another piece of state in the redux store and update that state from the front end component once a value from the drop down has been selected?
   or 3. Try and handle it here with setting a variable in the reducer and logic to return that if necessary?

Like I said, I'm building this to try and learn a bit about react and redux, but i'm really not sure what the way to handle this is...

Answer (score 0):

update, as suspected... neither of those options were correct. I was not calling the link correctly in the component generating the click event to drill into the detail content item. Implementing Link from react-router-dom was the right way to handle this.